# Adding custom menu page in Voyager admin panel gives 404

Tags: laravel, admin, voyager

I have installed laravel 5.4 and Voyager 1.0.17

In the settings->menu builder->admin i'm adding new menu.
Then adding resources/views/vendor/testpage/browse.blade.php

And once I click on the menu/testpage i'm getting 404.

If I'm changing one of existing pages (categories, posts) same way (adding to .../vendor/posts/browse.blade.php its working well, but not the any other custom page.

Ive searched for a while now, but there is no solution for this.

Please advice.
Thanks a lot.

Update:
screenshots added:

[image: menu builder]

[image: views testpage]

Comment: can you add screenshots for your current menu builder including the address bar and the views folder content?, i can help you with this

Comment: hey, i did. please check. thanks!

Comment: according to the docs, resource  folder in the /views/vendor/voyager/RESOURCE should be the slug that you've assigned to the table, make sure of this and lemme know

Comment: Hey, according to the docs resources/views/vendor/voyager/slug-name
this is right. 
https://voyager.readme.io/docs/overriding-views

Comment: as far as I found, the problem is with permissions.

Comment: but it's weird as it shouldn't return 404, 402 instead

Answer (score 2):

I am writing an example for you to make changes according to your needs.

add this route in web.php below routes folder :

```
Route::get('test', function(){
      return view('test');
    });
```

create test.blade.php in resources>views folder whit this code example:

```
@extends('voyager::master')




  <h1>This is awesome!!</h1>
```